# How can I identify unused i18n keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on an existing Rails app and am using a localization file, `en.yml`, to hold most of the app's text. At the moment, we aren't localizing into any other languages, so there's just the one file, but the fact that we're putting `translate('some.key')` into our views means that adding another language will be as simple as adding another file - say, `sp.yml`

The problem is, `en.yml` has grown to the point that I doubt all the keys are being used.

Apart from `git grepping` for `translate` calls using each key, is there a quick way to identify localization keys that aren't being explicitly called by the app?

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at this article about  ["Key issues internationalizing your app"](http://selleo.com/blog/technologies/key-issues-internationalizing-your-app2/). The paragraph that interests you is: "**Getting rid of unused translations**".

Specifically, it recommends looking through your source code and also logging what translation keys get used in your production app, as follows:

```
module I18n
  module Registry
    protected
    def lookup(locale, key, scope = [], options = {})
      @log ||= Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'i18n_registry.log'))
      @log.info key
      super
    end
  end
end

I18n::Backend::Simple.send :include, I18n::Registry
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

## I18n-tasks gem

I just heard about this gem, which includes a task to show "potentially unused translations".

https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks

Comment: Potentially unused in a sense that it will give false positives for hard to detect cases, e.g. `I18n.t(method_returning_the_key)`. It is possible to ignore such keys with `config/i18n-tasks.yml`.

Comment: @glebm - Thanks for the clarification. By the way, how did you find this mention of your gem so quickly?

Comment: I searched for the name on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been many years since I first arrived to this question as I had the exact same problem. The problem hasn't grown smaller, I am more frustrated than ever.

Here is an experimental project, it hooks into the translate lookup and increments the translation key counter in Redis:

https://github.com/paladinsoftware/i18n-counter

The idea is that you can pull the stats and compare. (WIP for the moment, I would love help ofc)

You may ask: "won't that slow down the lookups?"

And you are right of course, but the overhead is hardly noticeable, check out this benchmark.

```
require 'benchmark'
n = 100000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { ENV['ENABLE_I18N_COUNTER'] = 'true'; n.times do ; I18n.translate('application.contract_not_available.header'); end }
  x.report { ENV['ENABLE_I18N_COUNTER'] = 'false'; n.times do ; I18n.translate('application.contract_not_available.header'); end }
end

 ---------------------------------------------
| Benchmark  | Seconds   | Sec pr translation |
|------------| --------- | ------------------ |
| with redis | 48.280000 | 0.0004828          |
| without    |  9.010000 | 0.0000901          |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

The overhead being about 3 ms pr lookup. It boils down to the number of lookups you do per page/request.

Answer (score -1):

Get the ones that are actively used, then remove the rest. That's what I use.

*Actually I set them to `active=0` but that may not work for you*

**Update**
Turns out I was unclear.

There are two ways to look at this: from the source files or from the translation files. If you look from the source files you need to identify all strings that are in use and finally remove all unused strings.

If you look from the translation files, you need to look at the source and determine whether they are still used, as you mentioned in the question.

There's no other way.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I'm talking about lines in a file. Are you talking about database rows?

Comment: I don't have any experience with rails, but most i18n solutions I know have a way of exporting all translatable strings. Export all translatable strings, then loop through all strings and check which ones aren't used anymore (look in your export).

Comment: I'm not asking how to compare two localization files; I'm asking how to check which localization keys are used by the app's code.

Comment: And I'm answering that question :-) One file uses the translations, the other file holds the translations.

Comment: "The other file" is my application code, which spans dozens of files. I'm really looking for a Rails-specific solution; perhaps a gem which exercises the app code and looks for calls to the translate method.

Comment: Then how did you generate the translation files in the first place? Didn't you export them with a tool like `xgettext`? If you manually moved all translatable strings to a file then you usually end up doing everything manually. If you used standard tools like `xgettext`, these things become a lot easier.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try

```
$ ruby script/plugin install http://github.com/o2sources/unused_translations/tree/master
$ script/unused_translations config/locales/en.yml
```

Source:
http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/1547-unused-i18n-translations